# Install .NET 5 without having admin rights

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-5

How to install .NET 5 without downloading the SDK from Microsoft website?

Answer (score 2):

I have enrolled for a .NET5 + Angular course and i needed to install .NET5 SDK on my machine. One way to install is to download the SDK from Microsoft website and run the installer. But in my case i do not have admin access over my machine and cannot install the SDK following above mentioned process but i do have VS 2019 Professional installed. The method i followed was open Visual Studio Installer for 2019 and update VS 2019 (this does not require admin rights). We can verify this by clicking on Modify button and check under Individual Components for .NET5

[image]

[image]

We can also check under Programs and Features a new entry is added for .NET SDK 5.0.400
[image]

Hope this helps someone in my situation!

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an answer specific to .net 5. If you dont have admin access just download the binaries from the microsoft website and unzip the contents in a folder. As simple as that. Remember to download the binaries and not the installables. The draw back with this is that commands like "dotnet" will not be available globally on your machine. You will need to run this command from the downloaded folder. For example "unzippedfolder...\dotnet new sln"